# How to Create multiple buttons in android

Tags: android

I tried the below code to create multiple buttons through programatically but it creates a single button as per my application i need to create a button based on input. For example if the input is 3 means i need to create three buttons in a layout. For your reference i attached the sample image and my code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array_of_btn_input.size(); i++) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            layout.setLayoutParams(params);
            Button button1 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
            button1.setLayoutParams(params1);
            button1.setText("button");

            layout.addView(button1);
            main_layer.addView(layout);
}
```

[image]

Comment: What type of view is the main layout? It's possible it's just stacking the buttons on top of each other.

Comment: 1) Why do you need a LinearLayout for each button ?

Comment: 2) What is the global container ?

Comment: Because of relative layout you have placed them on top of eachother, i wrote answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if in your example, your global container (main_layer) is a relativelayout or a frame layout, you have placed them on top of eachother. So you can't see the one on the back order.

Try this pls,

```
LinearLayout main_layer= (LinearLayout) findViewById(id.main_layer);


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
layout.setLayoutParams(params);
Button button1 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
button1.setLayoutParams(params1);
button1.setText("button");

layout.addView(button1);
main_layer.addView(layout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating multiple new linear layouts within the for loop. Linear layout need to be taken out of the for loop and just try adding the buttons in it.

1st run of for loop creates a new linear layout and adds a button

2nd run of for loop creates a new linear layout and adds a button on the top of previous added layout

Answer (score 0):

Here you are creating a new LinearLayout per button... Try something more like...

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
layout.setLayoutParams(params);

for (int i = 0; i < array_of_btn_input.size(); i++) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    Button button1 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    button1.setLayoutParams(params1);
    button1.setText("button");

    layout.addView(button1);
```

}

main_layer.addView(layout);

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
LinearLayout llParent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llParent);
llParent.removeAllViews();
for (int i = 0; i < array_of_btn_input.size(); i++) {
    BSView b = new BSView(this, new SimpleThumbBean(i + 1, bsList
            .get(i).getLabel(), bsList.get(i).getThumbUrl()));
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llDynamic = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    llDynamic.weight = 1f;
    llParent.addView(b, llDynamic);
}
```

llParent is a defined Layout and make sure you call removeAllViews() before adding layouts dynamically into it.

BSView is my own custom View. You can set BSView into ordinary Button as you need it.